# Enum in Modules

Tags: enums, julia

I am trying to use enums inside modules but without success:

```
# module for testing enums
module EE
export EnumTest
@enum EnumTest uu ii dd 
end # module
```

I did `importall EE` in the repl. After this I checked the presence of the enum values with `instances(EE.EnumTest)` with the result

```
 (uu::EE.EnumTest = 0, ii::EE.EnumTest = 1, dd::EE.EnumTest = 2)
```

(as expected).

When I am trying to return/print the value with `uu::EE.EnumTest` it is just throwing an exception `UndefVarError`. I don't expect this. How to use the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `export` statement in your module just makes the names you list available for use outside the module.  You only listed `EnumTest` — the overall type of the enum — and none of the instances.

You can access the instances by fully-qualifying them with the module name (`EE.uu`) or by adding them to the export list (`export EnumTest, uu, ii, dd`) and `using EE`.  Note that `importall` isn't needed here and is deprecated in favor of `using` in cases like these in 0.7.

Comment: So there is no way to give the enums themself a namespace like in C++ with enum class or in D with enums?

Comment: Just put them in a (sub)module and don't export them.  It's not automatic, but it's very easy to do.

Comment: You would probably want `using .EE`, if it is contained inside another module.